# Is there a size limit for raw resources in an android app?

Tags: android, svg, size

I am using svg files in my android application. Just wanted to know what should be the size of the file that should be kept in the raw folder in resources.

Answer (score 0):

Raw folder can be of **any size** if your **Minimum Reqiured SDK is API 9 or 2.3 above**.
There is limitation in lower version because of low system performance.

Comment: Just a quick addition. While the statement above is correct, if you intend to publish your app to Google Play, you have to keep your apks size less than 50MB. After that point, you'd have to use apk expansion files.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html